# Sql grab substring in a column after a different word

Tags: sql, sqlite, substring, logparser

How do you get the substring after a word if you there are two different words? I want the substring after the word 'is' and 'isn't'. Suppose I have the columns as below. How do I just grab the substring after 'is' and 'isn't' in a single query? What I have creates another column and has null values. I just want one column and no null values

```
"bob is very cool"
"Cris isn't cool"

SELECT SUBSTR(String, INDEX_OF(String,'isnt'),strlen(string)) as column2, 
SUBSTR(String,INDEX_OF(String,'is'),STRLEN(String)) as column1 from 
'[LOGFILEPATH]' where column2 <> null or column1 <>null
```

expected results

```
 "very cool"
 "cool"
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: im using sqlite with logparser and python

Comment: Add one row without is and isn't. And another one with "is is". And specify the expected result as well.

Comment: wait what do you mean? im a little confused

Answer (score 0):

Use `INSTR` to find the position of the keyword.

```
select case when instr(test_string,'isn''t') > 0           
            then substr(test_string,
                 instr(test_string,'isn''t')+5,
                 length(test_string))
            when instr(test_string,' is ') > 0           
            then substr(test_string,
                 instr(test_string,' is ')+4,
                 length(test_string))
            else null
        end as stringAftKeyWord
from table
```

Comment: Watch out for words like `isolate` and `wisdom`.

Comment: unfortunatley logparser doesnt support 'when' clause with multiple expressions :(

Comment: @claudiebro, that is not true. LogParser does support the two flavors of `CASE` statements, `CASE expression WHEN value...` and `CASE WHEN expression...`

Comment: i dont think so, when i try it it doesnt like it

Answer (score 0):

You could do a Case statement if you know what words you need.

```
SELECT 'bob is very cool' AS whoIsCool INTO #temp
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES ('Cris isn''t cool')
SELECT * FROM #temp

SELECT 
    CASE
       WHEN whoIsCool like '%is %' THEN
           SUBSTRING(whoIsCool, CHARINDEX('is', whoIsCool) + LEN('is'), CHARINDEX('is', whoIsCool) + LEN(whoIsCool))
       WHEN whoIsCool like '%isn''t%' THEN
           SUBSTRING(whoIsCool, CHARINDEX('isn''t', whoIsCool) + LEN('isn''t'), CHARINDEX('isn''t', whoIsCool) + LEN(whoIsCool))
    END as newCool
FROM #temp
DROP TABLE #temp
```

Also, you should probably use CONTAINS() instead of wildcards (like I have here).